# How to update a UILabel with UIButton in custom cell in Swift?

Tags: uitableview, swift, cells

I'm trying to implement a counter as a `UILabel` using + and - `UIButtons` in a custom cell. I've managed to reference the row using addTarget and tags for the buttons, however I'm not sure how to update the label, adding or subtracting 1 each time a button is pressed.

I've tried accessing the `cell.drinkQtyLabel.text` directly from the `addDrink` function but that clearly doesn't work. My research pointed to using delegates, but I'm not proficient enough with Xcode to know what to do with that info.

Here is a screen shot of the cells:

[image: iphone6 custom cells]

Here is the custom `cell.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ProductListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var drinkNameLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
@IBOutlet var drinkVesselLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
@IBOutlet var drinkSizeLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
@IBOutlet var drinkPriceLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
@IBOutlet var drinkQtyLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
@IBOutlet weak var subtractDrinkButton: UIButton! = UIButton()
@IBOutlet weak var addDrinkButton: UIButton! = UIButton()



required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}



override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)



    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

and the `cellForRowAtIndex` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:ProductListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ProductListTableViewCell
    let drink:PFObject = self.productListData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
    var Qty = 1

    cell.drinkNameLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.drinkVesselLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.drinkSizeLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.drinkPriceLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.drinkQtyLabel.alpha = 0

    cell.drinkNameLabel.text = drink.objectForKey("name") as? NSString
    cell.drinkVesselLabel.text = drink.objectForKey("vessel") as? NSString
    cell.drinkSizeLabel.text = drink.objectForKey("size") as? NSString
    cell.drinkPriceLabel.text = drink.objectForKey("price") as? NSString
    cell.drinkQtyLabel.text = String(Qty)



            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                cell.drinkNameLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.drinkVesselLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.drinkSizeLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.drinkPriceLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.drinkQtyLabel.alpha = 1
            })

    cell.addDrinkButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.drinkQtyLabel.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.addDrinkButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("addDrink:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)



    return cell
}

func addDrink(sender:UIButton){

    println("Added drink in row \(sender.tag)"

    //update cell.drinkQtyLabel.text 
        }

}
```

Pseudo code of what I want might look something like:

```
func addDrink(sender: UIButton){

    for cell at indexPath(sender.tag){
        cell.drinkQtyLabel.text = int(cell.drinkQtyLabel.text) + 1
    }
}
```

But I know this isn't a solution!

Comment: It wonders me a bit, that accessing the label text does not update it. Are you sure, that you are setting it to the proper value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm trying to set the label from within the addDrink function. I've updated the question with some pseudo code of how my brain thinks it should work! Thanks for looking at this

Comment: I mean, you are setting it to a certain value. E.g. after touching "+" the value should be 2, right? So the question is, can you verify that your code attempts to set "2" to the label.

Comment: It does not. Currently there is no code in the addDrink function other than a println. All i've managed to do is retrieve the row of the index path of the pressed button. The label doesn't seem to be visible from within the addDrink function (which is probably obvious to more seasoned programmers)